# prevent angular from triggering filter function and binding function of directive for hidden elements

Tags: angularjs

As far as I know angular doesn't link hidden HTML elements, so I assume when the viewport width is 500px or larger, the first paragraph is not linked (the `mydirective` link function is not triggered).

```
<p mydirective>{{content | customFilter}}<p>
<p mydirective>{{content}}<p>


p {
    display:block;
}

@screen and min-width:500px {
    p:nth-child(1) {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

However, the filtering function is still triggered as well as binding function for `mydirective`. Is there any way to prevent angular from triggering filter function and binding function for hidden HTML elements?

The task here for me is to show filtered data for small screens (less than 500px) and unfiltered data for larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS to hide and show elements, use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) which will then remove the elements from the DOM and therefore prevent any Angular related magic happening for those elements (Until you want them back again).

Comment: This is an option, but the problem with this approach is that I should in javascript detect viewport size changes which is not a good thing